# Keyboard layout visualized: which character is where - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I remember that it was possible to call an illustration on-screen that showed where actual characters are on the keyboard according to the current layout.

But now on Windows 10 Pro version 21H2 I cannot find this option.

Could you help with where on the user interface I can activate this visual keymap illustration?

Also could I have used some better terminology?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the accessibility feature “On-screen keyboard”?

Comment: @DanielB I did not know about the context in which Windows offers this functionality (as in: accessibility), I just wanted to use something more efficient than trial-and-error to find some special keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onscreen keyboard illustration in the latest version of Windows 10 Pro still exists.

Open Settings, in the Search bar type in Tun on Onscreen Keyboard and the option comes up and it does work.

[image: Windows 10 on screen keyboard]

Comment: I don't seem to have a direct sequence to a "Keyboard" item in my "Settings" app. I do have "Typing settings". But by searching for "on screen" as you suggested, then yes, this comes up, and I can enable it.

Comment: Ahh, brilliant, I wanted to find the special characters that are activated by AltGr, and they were not initially displayed, contrary to my expectation. But I figured out that one has to press and hold `AltGr` to reveal those characters. It's that much interactive. Solves my need, accepted, thank you!

Comment: Found the direct path as well: Settings > Ease of access > Keyboard... :|